# How to search by date using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert a date to a string so I can search on the value entered. I am using a lamda expression and DateTime.ParseExact as I just want to use the short date entered.

This is my connection to the database:

```
var devices = db.Devices
            .Include(d => d.DeviceType)
            .Include(d => d.ManufacturerModel)
            .Include(d => d.ManufacturerModel.Manufacturer);
```

and my search

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString5))
{
    devices = devices.Where(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.DateReceived,'dd/MM/yyyy');
}
```

Comment: And whats the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: `Where` takes a _predicate_ which needs to return a boolean value.  Did you mean to compare the data returned to something or do you just want items where the parse is successful?

Comment: If you're trying to convert a date to a string, why are you trying to parse anything?  Just call `ToString` with your format, surely?  It's quite unclear what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: It's not clear, what you are trying to achieve with this snippet, Could you please be more specific

Comment: `devices.ToList().Where(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s.DateReceived,'dd/MM/yyyy') == searchString5`

Comment: `date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` tried?

Comment: I'm trying to perform a search for when a person enters 6/29/2015 on the field DateReceived. I started with devices = devices.Where(s => s.(DateReceived.ToString()).Equals(searchString5));

Comment: perhaps you should try a different way since you seem to be having issues doing it with a Lambda..

Comment: Instead of allowing your user to enter a string, use a control that is designed to enter a date and then just search for the date value and not bother converting it to a string.

Comment: With using a control that is designed to enter a date to search for a date I think I might try a datepicker

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare two dates easily, because you still need to compare hours, minutes and seconds.

Instead, you want to let user to choose ranges - From Date and To Date.

For example,

```
var query = db.Devices
            .Include(d => d.DeviceType)
            .Include(d => d.ManufacturerModel)
            .Include(d => d.ManufacturerModel.Manufacturer);

string fromDate = "1/15/2016", toDate = "1/30/2016";
    DateTime fromDateTime, toDateTime;

if(!DateTime.TryParse(fromDate, out fromDateTime))
{
    // Make fromDateTime to Start of Day - 1/15/2016 12:00:00 AM
    fromDateTime = fromDateTime.Date;
    query = query.Where(x => x.Date >= fromDateTime);
}

if (!DateTime.TryParse(toDate, out toDateTime))
{
    // Make toDateTime to End of day - 1/30/2016 11:59:59 PM
    toDateTime = toDateTime.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
    query = query.Where(x => x.Date <= toDateTime);
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching dates with entity can be rough I converted my string into a DateTime format then searched each part of the date to pull the date that was needed I'm not sure if this is the direction you wanted to go but this worked for me

```
                    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(SearchText); 
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Date.Month == date.Month
                                          && x.Date.Day == date.Day
                                          && x.Date.Year == date.Year);
```

// Let me know if this worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Don't use strings. Let the framework do the heavy lifting for you.

```cs
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(searchString5, out dt)) {
    qry = qry.Where(s => s.Fecha.Date == dt.Date);
} else {
    throw new Exception("Bad input");
}
```

The generated SQL (in my case) is as follows, which is quite good.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2016-03-19 00:00:00.000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
   ...
FROM 
   ...
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[Fecha]) = @p0
```

Here's a tip: use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to write and analyze your queries. It's free (and the paid version is cheap but it's absurdly powerful and useful.)